# Shorten multiple ANDs + ORs in one if-statement (+ XOR, regex)

Tags: java, regex, if-statement

I program a robot in Java and I want it to analyse something if a rock exists and if there's a hill on the right or on the left as well. I have already tried:

```
if (rockExisting() && hillExisting("left") || rockExisting() && hillExisting("right"))
```

It's working, but can I shorten it? (E.G. with redex, a friend told me but the Java Reference defeats me.) And can I also use a logical XOR? (like if there's a hill on the right and left, the condition would be false? ("^" doesn't work for me)

Comment: What about just factoring out the common bit? `rockExisting() && (hillExisting("left") || hillExisting("right"))`

Comment: OP, by convention methods that return `boolean` have names starting with `is` or `has`, sometimes `exists`, `was`, or `had`. It'll help maintainers, including yourself, to follow the standard coding conventions. That applies to the arguments to `isHill()`, plus it's a very bad practice to have magic strings, or strings that identify state. Use an enum as the argument type for `isHill`.

Comment: "("^" doesn't work for me)" is too vague. What is the code, and what exactly is the symptom?

Comment: @LewBloch Already got a solution.. ty anyways!

Comment: All right, but for future reference do provide details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (rockExisting() && hillExisting("left") || rockExisting() && hillExisting("right"))
```

is the same thing as

```
if (rockExisting() && (hillExisting("left") || hillExisting("right")))
```

as `&&` has higher precedence than `||`

Comment: This is also a good jump-off point to accomplish the XOR nature for the `hillExisting` clauses.

Comment: But I don't know how / with what char.

Comment: @LarryGrabb:  Remember:  XOR is `^`.  In order to successfully have an XOR statement, you need to be comparing two values which can be compared in this fashion.  Remember that you want to check if a hill is on the left, on the right, but not both.  This gives you the logical "if a hill is on the left OR on the right".  That's all the hint I'll give you.

Comment: @Makoto Ahh got it. It's ^ not ^^, ty !

Answer (score 1):

With [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws) you can simplify the if term/conditions.  You could write:

```
if (rockExisting() && (hillExisting("left") || hillExisting("right")))
```

according to the distributive law

`(a∧b)∨(a∧c) = a∧(b∨c)`

- `∧` ... `&&`
- `∨` ... `||`
- `a` ... rockExisting()
- `b` ... hillExisting("left")
- `c` ... hillExisting("right")